# Spring - Excluding a bean from a package from being scanned

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

If I have about 50 spring beans in package com.xyz.abc and I want to exclude 2 of those beans from being treated as a bean , is there a way to do it? I am using Spring Boot.

```
@ComponentScan({'com.xyz.abc'})
```

There is a class Automobile.class which I don't want to be treated as Spring Bean. However I have Car.class which extends Automobile to be treated as spring bean.

Comment: What about the obvious solution of removing the `@Component` annotation from the unwanted classes?

Comment: Hi Kryger , I have received these beans as part of jar which is shared by multiple teams. Hence I wouldn't be able to removed @Component annotation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can exclude specific classes from being scanned into beans with the [`excludeFilters`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#excludeFilters--) parameter of the `@ComponentScan` annotation.

This allows for the exclusion of specific classes, classes matching a given pattern...

For example, to exclude `firstClass` and `secondClass` you would write:

```
@ComponentScan(value = {'com.xyz.abc'}, excludeFilters = {
  @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = { firstClass.class, secondClass.class })
})
```